# How do you insert a global / environment variable inside a Postman request body?

Tags: postman

I am generating a custom email address within the pre-request script and I set it as a global environment variable, i.e.

```
pm.environment.set('email', email)
```

​
My request body can be seen below:

```
{
  "email": "{{email}}",
  "country": "CH",
  "password": "test",
}
```

However the server always returns me a 401 response, I am assuming that Postman is not resolving the variable for some reason, hence actually trying to post '{{email}}' as email parameter, which will be rejected by the server to prevent js injections.

Comment: What does the Postman Console say? That will tell you what is actually being sent in the request. Is the Environment selected when you make the request?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! it's actually resolving it... But why doesn't the server let me allow to post the request then? because if i enter a generated mail manually instead of resolving it as a variable, it gets through..

Comment: Have you tried it without the quotes?

Comment: yes, no luck unfortunately

Comment: What is `email`, is that a variable in your code or just a placeholder for your question? Are you sure that those details are valid, it's a 401 so that would suggest the creds are wrong? We can't see all of what you have in your app so all the suggestions are guessing at the moment.

Comment: email is a variable in my code, yes. all details are stated correct, hence i am confused..

Answer (score 0):

First,
**pm.environment.set('email', email)** this set environmental variable not as global variable.

So if you are doing **pm.environment.set('email', email)** like this then make sure you have selected the correct envionment while sending the request.

Second,
You can set email as global variable using **pm.globals.set("variable_key", "variable_value");**

Also 401 response code means **Unauthorized error** which means authentication for the request is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I've tried both - setting global and env variables (while selecting the correct environment). Didn't work. 
Yes, I am aware of 401 meaning but since I get a 200 for posting a normal email, I am just assuming that the server returns a misleading error code.